# Using the tailwind target selector to style a non-direct child with a set id property

Tags: tailwind-css

Can anyone advise the correct way for me to target the child div with the id "test" when hovering the parent div, using tailwind? The documentation doesn't seem to provide exactly what I need.

````
<div className={'flex cursor-pointer'} onClick={handleToggle} onKeyDown={handleToggle}>
      <label className="relative mr-2 inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="peer sr-only"
          checked={enabled}
          readOnly
          disabled={isDisabled}
        />
        <div id="test" className={`peer h-4 w-7 rounded-full bg-transparent`} />
      </label>
      {label && (
        <Text level="xs" className="grey-dark">
          {label}
        </Text>
      )}
   </div>
    ```
````

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but this demo targets the element with id of `test` when hovering over the parent. https://play.tailwindcss.com/IIeRyEdQB9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`group` with `group-hover` to style based on parent state](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex cursor-pointer group">
  <label class="relative mr-2 inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      class="peer sr-only"
      checked=checked
    />
    <div id="test" class="peer h-4 w-7 rounded-full bg-transparent group-hover:bg-red-500"></div>
  </label>
  <Text level="xs" class="grey-dark">
    {label}
  </Text>
</div>
```